# Auto increment row number in excel sheet

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-formula, vba

I have the following formula written in the cell B5

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(COLORINDEXOFRANGE(Data!D10:HO10,FALSE,1)=COLORINDEXOFONECELL(Data!$F$3,FALSE,1)))
```

When i drag down from B5 to the next row, the cells in the formula change to `COLORINDEXOFRANGE(Data!D11:HO11,FALSE,1)`

But i want the column number to remain the same and want just the row number to change to, for example `COLORINDEXOFRANGE(Data!E10:HO10,FALSE,1)` for the cell C5 and `COLORINDEXOFRANGE(Data!F10:HO10,FALSE,1)` for cell D5 and so on.

COLORINDEXOFRANGE is an inbuilt function that i found on the internet.

Please help.  Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Is the behavior you want not the built in default behavior? Can you not achieve what you want by using `$` in the formulas?

Comment: @Brad i tried to use $, but when we drag down, the Row number increments, for example D10 changes to D11 but not to E10. As Sean suggested below, i need to use OFFSET but i was not able to figure out where to write 'OFFSET' in my formula

Comment: Do you want to sort of reverse the incrementing? dragging vertically would normally increment the rows property but you want to instead keep your row but increment the column. and vice versa for horizontal dragging, you want vertical offsetting? Kind of as through you had transposed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to change from a horizontal to a vertical reference, I have used `OFFSET`, where I reference the values in another sheet using `=OFFSET('Forecast'!$I$17,COLUMN()-3,0)` so that the column() of the reference going across becomes the row reference

Comment: hi, i checked the same, it sounds so simple and easy but for some reason the D does not change to E when i drag it down, and as you said 10, HO and 10 remain the same as there is a $. Can you please check it?

Comment: ok.. I read this wrong - the drag down would not change how it moves across, so the D would not change. To do that type of change, I have used `OFFSET`> I will fix my answer

Answer (score 3):

If the end of the range remains the same then you could use `INDEX` to change the start of the range only, i.e. replace `Data!D10:HO10` with

`=INDEX(Data!D$10:HO$10,ROWS(B$5:B5)):Data!HO$10`

INDEX formulas of this type are only semi-volatile (they re-calculate when sheet is opened) which is perhaps preferable to fully volatile `OFFSET` and `INDIRECT` functions. Also `ROWS` function is better than `ROW` as it will cope with rows being inserted (or deleted) above the formula without changing the result

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to get around this dragging a dropping formulas to fixed references cells :

1. To answer your question literally you can reference they current row number using `ROW()`, so `ROW() - 1` gives the previous row number.
2. But this isn't going to work in your case because you are referencing a range. Another function is `INDIRECT()`, have a look at the documentation, but this could be used as such INDIRECT("R5C" & COLUMN(), FALSE)
3. Because option #2 tends to make formulas very long and (almost) unreadable sometimes you can get away with a [named range](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20named%20range)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: dragging a value down, didn't increment as expected. The problem was that I had filters applied to the data. Removing the filter restored the functionality.

Comment: It should be comment.